# how to combine two Firestore collections?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, rxdart

```
Example code 
 
toys = toysRef.where('postState', isEqualTo: 'recruiting').orderBy('createdAt', descending: true).snapshots();
fruits = fruitsRef.where('postState', isEqualTo: 'recruiting').orderBy('createdAt', descending: true).snapshots();
```

hi I'm trying to combine or merge two streams
I want to show toys and fruits order by desc with one StreamBuilder Widget
There is a common field ['createdAt']

[image]

I want to implement like this.
if some item added to firestore , it should show on realtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use StreamGroup from [rxdart](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) to merge your toys and fruits.

```
StreamGroup<List<QuerySnapshot>> combinedStreams = StreamGroup<List<QuerySnapshot>>.merge([
  toysRef.where('postState', isEqualTo: 'recruiting').orderBy('createdAt', descending: true).snapshots(),
  fruitsRef.where('postState', isEqualTo: 'recruiting').orderBy('createdAt', descending: true).snapshots()
]);
```

and to finally have them sorted in a stream, you could have:

```
StreamBuilder<List<QuerySnapshot>>(
  stream: combinedStreams,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<QuerySnapshot>> snapshot) {
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> combinedData = [];
    for (QuerySnapshot snap in snapshot.data) {
      combinedData.addAll(snap.docs);
    }

    combinedData.sort((a, b) => b['createdAt'].compareTo(a['createdAt']));

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: combinedData.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        // Build your UI
      }
    );
  }
)
```

You should use ListView.builder so that you have a performant list, and not render all the elements at once (would really lag your UI if you'd have a lot of elements).

Don't forget to check if snapshot has errors or is empty so that you can display a loader to the user or an error message.

Comment: Can we get in touch? Sent you email via links on https://www.codingshadows.com/